# Where is now scipy.special inside Anaconda?

Tags: python, scipy

I have installed Anaconda 2 in Linux, presumably it has all the needed packges and more. I want to use the Spherical Harmonics function but I get

```
import scipy
Y = scipy.special.sph_harm(-M, L, theta, phi)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'special'
```

I have ran also `conda install scipy` and I still get the same error. I am using the standard [online manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.sph_harm.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to run `sph_harm()` and avoid the `AttributeError`:

```py
from scipy.special import sph_harm
M, L, theta, phi = 10, 20, 30, 80
Y = sph_harm(-M, L, theta, phi)
```